# How can I turn off jtable cell selection through mouse presses and drags

Tags: java, swing, jtable, selection

I am wanting to use a JTable but with a different cell selection method rather than clicking in the cells.  I am using the glasspane to allow users to draw a rectangle and am discovering what cells are contained in the rectangle to select.  But I am only wanting to select a cell if it is totally within the rectangle.  For example, imagine a simple 3 x 3 table.  The user my want to select the middle cell (1,1).  I want them to be able to click in the first cell 0,0 and drag down to cell 2,2 drawing the rectangle for selection.  But I don't want cells 0,0 or 2,2 selected.  Or get all 9 selected, for that matter.  This is a simplified example.  Drawing the rectangle might actually encompass cells from more than one table on the screen.

I looked into implementing the ListSelectionModel interface, but don't really want to try and rewrite that.  While experimenting I saw that setSelectionInterval() in the model was being called like crazy (for every single mouse movement) as I click and dragged around in the table.  What I would really like is to find a simple way to turn off whatever listener/mechanism is on the table that makes the calls to the SelectionModel, while keeping the model in place.  I'd still want it to report isSelectedIndex() for example.  I would tell the model what intervals are selected.

I figured that somewhere there's a mouse input adapter inherently built into JTables?  I'd like to turn it off if possible.

Thanks,
BBB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a generic / text-based question, you get a generic, text-based response. :) Start by uninstalling the MouseListeners installed on the table by default:

```
MouseListener[] listeners = myTable.getMouseListeners();
for (MouseListener l : listeners)
{
    myTable.removeMouseListener(l);
}
```

Then, add your own MouseListener to the table (use MouseAdapter if you want) and override the "mousePressed" / "mouseReleased" methods to record the points where the drag began, and drag ended. Determine the enclosing rectangle and call:

```
setRowSelectionInterval(#, #)
setColumnSelectionInterval(#,#)
```

to select one (or more) cells.

Comment: Good gravy!  I'm going to try this.  I just assumed that since I didn't install the mouse listener that I wouldn't have direct/simple access to remove it.  I thought the getMouseListeners() would just return the listeners I installed.  If this works I apologize for being ignorant.  But I'm not sure what you mean by 'generic / text-based question'.  I use text a lot ;)

Comment: For the love of all that is in the great pit humanity has been climbing out of, it works!  I did this with both MouseListeners and MouseMotionListeners and selections stopped.  The motion listener was getting the drag events and adding selection intervals also.

Comment: No offence meant, I was just kidding around with you, since you posted a question with a heavy description, but minimal code. :)